# C++11 Exception's destructor allows to throw now?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, destructor, c++98

any idea why 
virtual ~exception() throw() is in C++98,
but 
virtual ~exception() is in C++11?

What's the design decision that allows C++11 to throw in the destructor of the class `exception`?

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/):

c++98:

```
class exception {
public:
  exception () throw();
  exception (const exception&) throw();
  exception& operator= (const exception&) throw();
  virtual ~exception() throw();
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
}
```

c++11:

```
class exception {
public:
  exception () noexcept;
  exception (const exception&) noexcept;
  exception& operator= (const exception&) noexcept;
  virtual ~exception();
  virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the noexcept keyword and maybe wondered what it is all about?

Comment: Swapped the screenshots for code.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Did you notice the lack of `noexcept` on the destructor?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> What's the desing decision makes C++11 allow to throw in the destructor of the class `exception`?

There was no such design decision (fortunately!). In C++11, even explicitly declared destructors are qualified as `noexcept` by default. This can be evinced from paragraph 12.4/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> A declaration of a destructor that does not have an *exception-specification* is implicitly considered to have
>   the same *exception-specification* as an implicit declaration (15.4).

And from paragraph 15.4/14, which specifies what exception specification an implicit declaration has:

> An inheriting constructor (12.9) and an implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) have an
>   exception-specification. If `f` is an inheriting constructor or an **implicitly declared** default constructor, copy
>   constructor, move constructor, **destructor**, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   exception-specification specifies the type-id `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the exception-specification
>   of a function directly invoked by f’s implicit definition; `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly
>   invokes allows all exceptions, and **`f` has the exception-specification `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly
>   invokes allows no exceptions**.

Together, the above two paragraphs guarantee (given the declaration you quoted of `exception`'s destructor) that the destructor of `exception` won't throw.

This is also explicitly stated in paragraphs 18.8.1/7-8 of the C++11 Standard:

> `virtual ~exception();`
>
> 7 *Effects*: Destroys an object of class exception.
>
> 8 *Remarks*: **Does not throw any exceptions**.

Notice, that dynamic exception specifications (such as `throw()`) are deprecated in C++11. Per § D.4/1 of the Annex D:

> The use of *dynamic-exception-specifications* is deprecated.

Comment: You might want to add the citation for `noexcept` by default: [except.spec]§14. It sure isn't in the most intuitive place.

Comment: thanks! this makes a lot of sense althought I do not like "default" things at all!

Comment: @Angew: Sorry for the delay, had to leave for a while. I edited the answer, thank you!

Comment: @AndyProwl I just closed a question as a duplicate of this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025862/why-is-the-stdexception-destructor-not-noexcept/50025962), OP itself marks the question as a duplicate, but one of the answer has a good quote regarding exception specification of destructors in the standard library, which would be a great addition to this answer.