# Exception behavior C++14 vs C++98

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, c++98

I have written following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Myclass
{
    public:
    ~Myclass() 
    {
        //throw std::runtime_error("second (in destructor)");
        throw 1;
    }
};

void fun()
{
    Myclass obj;
}
int main()
{   
    try
    {
        fun();      
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
       std::cout << e.what();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
       std::cout << " ... default Catch" << std::endl; 
    }
    std::cout << "Normal" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run above program in `C++98` mode (cpp.sh) it prints

```
 ... default Catch
Normal
```

When I run it with `C++14` mode, it does not print anything.  **Why is there a change in this behavior?**

I do understand that whenever any exception occurred and any `destructor` (within stack unwinding process) throws any exception, it terminates the application. But here only one time exception is thrown from `try` block that is from `destructor`.

Comment: [Don't throw exceptions in destructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor).

Comment: g++ says: "main.cpp:12:15: warning: throw will always call terminate() [-Wterminate]" "main.cpp:12:15: note: in C++11 destructors default to noexcept"

Comment: The more relevant previous question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16540757/1858225

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since C++11, a destructor without an explicitly spelled out exception specification has the same exception specification as the default-generated one would have. In your case, the default-generated destructor would be `noexcept` (most default-generated destructors are), so your destructor is considered `noexcept` as well. Throwing from a `noexcept` function automatically calls `std::terminate`.

If you want the exception to be catchable, declare the destructor as throwing:

```
~Myclass() noexcept(false)
{
    //throw std::runtime_error("second (in destructor)");
    throw 1;
}
```

But before you do that, *reconsider.* It's a [**bad idea** to have throwing destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor).

Comment: `noexcept()` is...weird. Just `noexcept` or maybe `noexcept(true)`?

Answer (score 4):

Throwing exceptions from destructors is always a bad idea since if there's already an exception in flight (e.g. destructor called during stack unwinding) `std::terminate` will be called.

That said, C++11 added an implicit `noexcept(true)` to destructors (except cases listed below) and that means, again, `std::terminate` if throwing from a `noexcept(true)` destructor.

§12.4/3

> [class.dtor]
>   [ Note: A declaration of a destructor that does not have a noexcept-specifier has the same exception
>   specification as if had been implicitly declared (15.4). — end note ]

and §15.4/14

> [except.spec]
>   The exception specification for an implicitly-declared destructor, or a destructor without a noexcept-specifier,
>   is potentially-throwing if and only if any of the destructors for any of its potentially constructed subojects is
>   potentially throwing.

I strongly recommend restructuring your code in order **not** to throw in destructors.

Comment: There's `std::uncaught_exception(s)` to handle such cases. :)