# Why is the std::exception destructor not noexcept

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

The [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/%7Eexception) of the the C++11 [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) base class is not `noexcept`, and thus may (in theory) throw an exception, which consequent relaxed permission for all its derived classes (including `std::bad_alloc` and `std::runtime_error`). The destructor of the C++98 `std::exception` however had a `throw()` exception specification, indicating it was not permitted to throw exceptions. Why the difference? Why is it now permitted to throw exceptions? The permission is particularly odd given that the `std::exception` [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) are now `noexcept`: you can safely construct such an object, but you can not safely destroy it: the opposite of the normal behaviour.

Having the destructor of an exception class throw an exception is usually disastrous. What can cause `std::exception::~exception` to throw an exception?

Comment: That declaration shown on cppreference actually is `noexcept`. Destructors are `noexcept` unless declared `noexcept(false)`

Answer (score 6):

It is `noexcept(true)` indeed. Since C++11, for [destructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) with no exception specification explicitly provided the exception specification is considered to be `noexcept(true)`.

> Except that if no exception specification is explicitly provided, the exception specification is considered to be one that would be used by the implicitly-declared destructor (see below). In most cases, this is `noexcept(true)`. Thus a throwing destructor must be explicitly declared `noexcept(false)`. (since C++11)

Comment: A diabolic implementation would still be allowed to make this implicitly `noexcept(false)` by having an attribute that would not be `noexcept(true)`, no?

Comment: @Holt It should match the one for the implicitly-declared destructor; for `std::exception` it should be `noexcept(true)` unless `std::exception` is implemented with a base or member whose destructor is `noexcept(false)`...

Answer (score 1):

[[res.on.exception.handling]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#3):

> Destructor operations defined in the C++ standard library shall not throw exceptions. Every destructor in the C++ standard library shall behave as if it had a non-throwing exception specification.